# SQL Server 2016 Management Studio - Picking wrong source for Generate Scripts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, azure-sql-database

This is a new one for me.

I need to generate scripts for a database, and no matter what I do, it always defaults to my local instance of SQL Server, not the one I am actually clicking on / connected to in Management Studio. And I see no way to change it.

Here's an example.  In this case, I am connected to a SQL Azure database, the one I want to generate scripts for:

[image: Generate Scripts]

This pops up the wizard to generate the scripts.  However, at the last step, it is showing my **local** SQL database as the source.

Here's what I see (the name showing up is my *local* machine, *local* database name):

[image: Showing my local machine]

I am not connected to my local database, I've tried multiple steps here (shut down all SQL Server Express services on my machine so it can't see it, restart Management Studio, etc).

Yet it still picks the wrong source.

I've done this many times, however this is my first time trying with *SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate*.

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  13.0.13000.55
```

This can't possibly be an actual bug here with basic functionality?

Comment: Do you have the right permissions on the DB/server in Azure? Is the connection still functioning? I just tested with SSMS v 13.0.12500.29 and it works fine. Regressions are possible but AFAIK, this area has not been touched so odds are very low it's a regression bug.

Comment: @SQLmojoe Yes, connecting to the database works fine, querying data is fine in SSMS.  I just can't get it to stop trying to use my local machine as the source.  It's very odd.  I agree that it's unlikely it's a regression but I can't think of a way to resolve it.  I figured stopping all of my SQL services would prevent it from trying to use it but apparently that information is cached somewhere.

Comment: FWIW, I could not reproduce this issue - I see the Azure SQL DB server and database name.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get around the final confirmation dialog showing my local system as the source.

I did everything I could try, including disabling any and all SQL services on my local machine (so when I try to connect, it correctly fails), restarted SSMS, restarted my machine, and I had no luck.

As it turns out, this final dialog may just be incorrect for some reason.  I went ahead and ran this, after making sure 1) my local SQL Server instance had *no databases* in it, and 2) Shutting down all the services so it wouldn't be able to connect.

The final confirmation screen *still* showed my local machine, but I went ahead as a test (feeling safe nothing bad could happen ... it's just generating a script) ... and ...

It took the correct source database (the Azure DB), despite displaying something else in the confirmation dialog (a local DB ... that *no longer existed* once I deleted it).

I took it to Microsoft by [opening a support case](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2557189/sql-server-2016-rc-ssms-wrong-source-being-displayed-in-generate-scripts).  But this dialog is definitely not displaying what is actually going to occur in my situation.

[image: Wrong Source Database]